# "The caller does not have permission" error when creating new project using node gcloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud-node

I'm using node.js google api (npm gcloud package) to create a new project. this is a beta API. 
I'm getting an error: "The caller does not have permission" 
stack:

> ApiError: The caller does not have permission
>           at new util.ApiError (C:\app\bundle\a2\node_modules\gcloud\lib\common\util.js:92:10)
>           at Object.parseHttpRespBody (C:\app\bundle\a2\node_modules\gcloud\lib\common\util.js:170:30)
>           at Object.handleResp (C:\app\bundle\a2\node_modules\gcloud\lib\common\util.js:110:18)
>           at C:\app\bundle\a2\node_modules\gcloud\lib\common\util.js:422:12
>           at Request.onResponse [as _callback] (C:\app\bundle\a2\node_modules\gcloud\node_modules\retry-request\index.js:117:7)
>           at Request.init.self.callback (C:\app\bundle\a2\node_modules\gcloud\node_modules\request\request.js:199:22)
>           at Request.emit (events.js:110:17)
>           at Request. (C:\app\bundle\a2\node_modules\gcloud\node_modules\request\request.js:1036:10)
>           at Request.emit (events.js:129:20)
>           at IncomingMessage. (C:\app\bundle\a2\node_modules\gcloud\node_modules\request\request.js:963:12)

I already enabled "Google Cloud Resource Manager API".
Other calls works OK.
What may be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Cloud Resource Manager's `projects.create` method is invite only [per their documentation](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-project):

> The projects.create() method is in the Alpha stage. It might be changed in backward-incompatible ways and is not recommended for production use. It is not subject to any SLA or deprecation policy. Access to this feature is currently invite-only. For an invitation, contact our sales team.

Comment: Thanks Zack, according to node.js documentation it's beta!? https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-node/#/docs/v0.27.0/resource?method=createProject
I'm confused...

Comment: Every method of the Cloud Resource Manager API except `projects.create` is part of the beta, but `projects.create` is still in Alpha and requires an invite to use. The [gcloud docs](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-node/#/docs/v0.27.0/resource?method=createProject) are for the gcloud client, but the [Cloud Platform docs](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects/create) are the authoritative docs for the API itself.

Answer (score 1):

For that method, you must be authenticated as yourself, i.e. a service account JSON file won't work here. The only way to do that that I know of is by installing the gcloud SDK (https://cloud.google.com/sdk) and running `gcloud auth login`. When you instantiate gcloud, don't provide any credentials, only your project ID:

```
var gcloud = require('gcloud');
var resource = gcloud.resource({ projectId: 'grape-spaceship-123' });

// Now this should work:
resource.createProject('grape-spaceship-124', function(err, project) {});
```

Related material:

- gcloud SDK installation guide: https://cloud.google.com/sdk
- gcloud-node createProject API docs: https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-node/#/docs/v0.27.0/resource?method=createProject

Comment: Thanks, this didn't solve the problem, I'm getting the same error.